# Angular 2 best practices to get data from json or api

Tags: angular, crud

I have been trying to start using Angular2, but it looks that it has been changing a lot so I am not very sure if the way im doing is a good manner to do it or not.

I created a service to get data from a json, my objetive was to simulate a webapi response or something like that, so in my service I created a method just like this

```
loadJsonData() {

    return this.http.get('./assets/MyData.json').map(res => res.json());
  }
```

I call this method since my main component OnInit,

```
ngOnInit() {

       var games = new Array(data.games.length);
        for (var index = 0; index < data.games.length; index++) {
            games[index] = data.games[index].title;
        }
        this.games = games;
      });
  }
```

It works pretty good, but I would like to know the best practices to do this kind of process and it would be awesome if you have a recent guide to create a CRUD using angular, thank you everyone for your time to answer!

Comment: I don't see where you are calling the loadJsonData method?

Comment: I can tell from your loop that you're (hopefully) new to javascript world. If you are looking for good practices, you should complete the [tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/) in the official Angular site, and if you want to start a project, you should look for a boilerplate. I suggest [angular-seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an example service providing the basic CRUD operations. This code is presented as a Pluralsight course here: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-2-reactive-forms/table-of-contents

You can find the complete operational code here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-ReactiveForms

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

import { IProduct } from './product';

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
    private baseUrl = 'api/products';

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .do(data => console.log('getProducts: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    getProduct(id: number): Observable<IProduct> {
        if (id === 0) {
           return Observable.of(this.initializeProduct());
        };
        const url = `${this.baseUrl}/${id}`;
        return this.http.get(url)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .do(data => console.log('getProduct: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    deleteProduct(id: number): Observable<Response> {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        const url = `${this.baseUrl}/${id}`;
        return this.http.delete(url, options)
            .do(data => console.log('deleteProduct: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    saveProduct(product: IProduct): Observable<IProduct> {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        if (product.id === 0) {
            return this.createProduct(product, options);
        }
        return this.updateProduct(product, options);
    }

    private createProduct(product: IProduct, options: RequestOptions): Observable<IProduct> {
        product.id = undefined;
        return this.http.post(this.baseUrl, product, options)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .do(data => console.log('createProduct: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private updateProduct(product: IProduct, options: RequestOptions): Observable<IProduct> {
        const url = `${this.baseUrl}/${product.id}`;
        return this.http.put(url, product, options)
            .map(() => product)
            .do(data => console.log('updateProduct: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private extractData(response: Response) {
        let body = response.json();
        return body.data || {};
    }

    private handleError(error: Response): Observable<any> {
        // in a real world app, we may send the server to some remote logging infrastructure
        // instead of just logging it to the console
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }

    initializeProduct(): IProduct {
        // Return an initialized object
        return {
            id: 0,
            productName: null,
            productCode: null,
            tags: [''],
            releaseDate: null,
            price: null,
            description: null,
            starRating: null,
            imageUrl: null
        };
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

For Angular v6 and higher, use `HttpClient` instead of `Http` and the newest RxJS operators.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Product } from './product';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {
  private productsUrl = 'api/products';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.http.get<Product[]>(this.productsUrl)
      .pipe(
        tap(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }

  getProduct(id: number): Observable<Product> {
    if (id === 0) {
      return of(this.initializeProduct());
    }
    const url = `${this.productsUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<Product>(url)
      .pipe(
        tap(data => console.log('getProduct: ' + JSON.stringify(data))),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }

  createProduct(product: Product): Observable<Product> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    product.id = null;
    return this.http.post<Product>(this.productsUrl, product, { headers: headers })
      .pipe(
        tap(data => console.log('createProduct: ' + JSON.stringify(data))),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }

  deleteProduct(id: number): Observable<{}> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    const url = `${this.productsUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.delete<Product>(url, { headers: headers })
      .pipe(
        tap(data => console.log('deleteProduct: ' + id)),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }

  updateProduct(product: Product): Observable<Product> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    const url = `${this.productsUrl}/${product.id}`;
    return this.http.put<Product>(url, product, { headers: headers })
      .pipe(
        tap(() => console.log('updateProduct: ' + product.id)),
        // Return the product on an update
        map(() => product),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }

  private handleError(err) {
    // in a real world app, we may send the server to some remote logging infrastructure
    // instead of just logging it to the console
    let errorMessage: string;
    if (err.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      errorMessage = `An error occurred: ${err.error.message}`;
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      errorMessage = `Backend returned code ${err.status}: ${err.body.error}`;
    }
    console.error(err);
    return throwError(errorMessage);
  }

  private initializeProduct(): Product {
    // Return an initialized object
    return {
      id: 0,
      productName: null,
      productCode: null,
      tags: [''],
      releaseDate: null,
      price: null,
      description: null,
      starRating: null,
      imageUrl: null
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Deborah, that's exactly what I was looking for!